# Truncate tail de una linea en swift

Tags: swift2, swift, swift3

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo que me muestra los tweets que hay según el usuario que escriba.

El problema es que al poner el `Nombre de usuario` y seguido el `nombre la cuenta` me trunca el inicio del `nombre de usuario`, en vez de truncar el `nombre de la cuenta`. Lo explico mejor con ejemplos:

Así está ahora:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es como quiero que este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**EDITADO**

El primer `label`, el tipo de letra es `System Bold 18.0`, configurado a una linea

El segundo `label`, el tipo de letra es `System 13.0`, configurado a una linea

Las imágenes las he hecho con `paint`, por lo que puede que los tamaños y tipos de letra no se correspondan con la realidad

Comment: En lugar de poner una cosa al lado de la otra, ¿no puedes ponerla una encima de otra? ¿Y estás seguro que quieres poner las dos cosas? las dos dicen practicamente lo mismo, ¿No?

Comment: Entiendo que son 2 label diferentes? pues creo que deberías recalcar el tamaño una vez que sepas lo que tienes que escribir

Comment: El problema es tien que ser en una linea para poner la fecha debajo y que las dos ocupen el alto de la imagen @MarcLemien

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta y he puesto las configuraciones de los label @Spidvmp

Comment: Si pones la fecha arriba a la derecha en este formato: 27/09/2016 no te ocuparía tanto y debajo podrías poner lo de la cuenta. Sería una posibilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como te comentaba, creo que la mejor opción es que calcules lo que te va a ocupar cada uilabel y a partir de ahí cambias el frame y truncas tu manualmente el trozo de texto que quieras. El tamaño que ocupa lo sacas con eso:(esta en objC)

```
CGSize textSize = [label.text sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[label font]}];
```

Y si sabes cuanto sitio te queda, pues haces un poco de matemáticas. Para cambiar un frame, lo que tines que hacer es sacarlo, cambiarlo y asignarlo:

```
CGRect fr = self.etiqueta.frame;
fr = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height);
self.etiqueta.frame = fr;
```

los valores de x, y, width y height los tienes que calcular dependiendo del tamaño que te quede en la pantalla